# What is the ideal ec2 instance type to use for NAT servers for production?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

What is the ideal ec2 instance to type to use for NAT servers for production?

In our case, we expect high volume of requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than deploying an Amazon EC2 instance as a NAT, you could use the fully managed [NAT Gateway service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html).

The gateway has built-in redundancy for high availability. Each gateway that you create can handle up to 10 Gbps of bursty TCP, UDP, and ICMP traffic, and is managed by Amazon.

One thing to note: Each NAT Gateway operates in a single Availability Zone (AZ). For a Highly-Available solution, you should run a NAT Gateway in each AZ that you are using. Subnets should be configured to route traffic to the NAT Gateway in their own AZ.

See also: [AWS Blog: New – Managed NAT (Network Address Translation) Gateway for AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-managed-nat-network-address-translation-gateway-for-aws/)

Comment: Cool, did not know NAT gateway exists!

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage of AWS is scalability. 
You don't need to pay apfront and it's always possible to scale up and down with minimum effort.
I could suggest the following scenario:

1. Set up an m4.large instance (for exaple)
2. Deploy your service and monitor it. If perfromance is not enough or a server is to powerfull, change your instance type. The following article describes how to do it: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-resize.html
3. Perfrom the step 2 until you find an ideal option for your particluar case.